# What is a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what a JavaScript array is because traditional programming languages define an array as a contiguous area of storage that can be addressed using an offset.

Now, a normal JavaScript object can be addressed as:

```
myObj.myProperty = "my Value";
```

or

```
myObj["myProperty"] = "my Value";
```

So, a JavaScript array is simply using numbers instead of names in it's addressing:

```
myObj[0] = "my Value";
myObj.length // === 1
```

A JavaScript Array also has methods, such as slice(), and join().

Q: Is what I said so far true?

Comment: @harper89: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Slight correction on one point: "a JavaScript array is simply using numbers instead of names in it's addressing" -- it's actually still using strings.  When you type `myObj[0]`, it gets converted to `myObj['0']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JavaScript array is a hash object with array functions attached using `Array.prototype`.  Put simply, this is an "Array" in JavaScript:

```
var x = {
    length : 3,
    '0'    : 'first',
    '1'    : 'second',
    '2'    : 'third'
};
x.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
```

All of the array functions only act on indexes, as you would expect, however you can also do anything to an array object that you would do to a general JS object:

```
ary.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: @Neal - only because it's a syntax error in JS.  x['0'] works fine

Comment: @cwolves, yes i know that, but you stated that you van do the same operations as a normal object which you cannot.

Comment: @Neal - yes, you can.  You can't do `x.0` on a generic object either :)

Comment: @cwolves. yes but all of the indexes on an array object are usually numbers

Comment: @Neal - they're always numbers.  There's nothing you can do to a generic object that you can't do an array since `Array` inherits from `Object`.  The fact that dot notation doesn't work on numbers doesn't negate that, it just means that you can't access numeric properties the same way.

Comment: It would be cool to explain how `length` is updated: probably update whenever the new key is an integer (`a[4] = 0` then `a.length == 5`), but not otherwise (`a['b'] = 0` and `a.length` is unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

To a basic yes or no question: **Yes** all of what you said is true.

Here is a [whole array tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-array-basics/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects are associative arrays. Javascript has an Object called Array that has special methods for dealing with their data.

Comment: -1: very bad phrasing for newbies to JS.  JS arrays are NOT associative arrays.  When used as arrays, they act as normal indexed arrays.  When used as an object they're associative.  There are loads of arguments against using them as objects.

Answer (score 1):

a good read ( that got me going at start )
[Mastering Javascript Arrays](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays)

Comment: Thanks Ates!  I'll look at it later tonight!

Comment: lol, you ment "Thanks Dementic" :D he just fixed a misspell of mine. XD

Answer (score 1):

Any JavaScript array is an object that can use different objects* as keys, making it a hash.

*all objects different from strings will be converted to string `[object Object]`, so they will act as the same key! (thanks to cwolves :)

Comment: @cwolves - any "non string" value different from null and undefined will be converted into a string because all object property names are strings!

Comment: yes, I realize that, but saying that you can use "different objects as keys" implies that this will work as expected: `var x={}, y={}, z={};  x[y] = 1;  x[z] = 2;`, but in reality you'd get `x == {'[object Object]' : 2}`.  And FYI, `null` and `undefined` work too :)

Comment: Note that you can define your own `toString()` method on your objects and then they will be usable as keys (assuming you come up with a meaningful way of providing uniqueness).