# What is a jQuery Object?

Tags: terminology, jquery, definitions

JavaScript kind of redefines what an Array means because an array is an object with a `.length` property and methods like `.slice()` and `.join()`.

jQuery defines a jQuery object as "Array like", because it has a `length` property but it doesn't have certain array methods like `join()`.

If I were to define the jQuery object as an object, and forget about mentioning anything to do with an array, how would I define it?  What properties does it have besides length?

I guess all the methods are what you see in the documentation, far exceeding the number of methods that are in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a JavaScript Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445010/what-is-a-javascript-array)

Comment: The jQuery documentation has all the info you need: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A jQuery object is array-like which means that it contains zero or more indexes (properties which names are positive integers starting with zero). Besides those indexes, a jQuery object contains these properties:

- `length`
- `context`
- `selector`

And also around 140 inherited methods (which are defined on the `jQuery.prototype` object - you can do `console.dir(jQuery.prototype)` to get a full list... ).

Note that jQuery objects *do not* contain (or inherit) the Array methods (slice, substr, ...). If you want to execute those methods on your jQuery object, use `call`/`apply`.

---

For example, if you have 3 TEXTAREA elements on the page and you do this:

```
var j = $('textarea');
```

then this `j` jQuery object will contain these properties:

- `0` - reference to the first TEXTAREA element
- `1` - reference to the second TEXTAREA element
- `2` - reference to the third TEXTAREA element
- `length` - which is `3`
- `context` - reference to the `document` object
- `selector` - which is `'textarea'`
- plus all those inherited methods...

Answer (score 2):

the jQuery object is an object which has

- a length property
- numeric properties which reference the items from the select (0,1,2,3...)
- bindings to jQuery functions
- additional jQuery properties

The length and numeric properties allow the object to respond like an array.  You can run it in a `for` loop or use functions like `map` or `each` on it.

I would recommend using your browser's debugger or Firebug and inspect a jQuery object.  That will teach you a lot about how it is structured.