# Concatenate in jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, concatenation

Simple problem. I have a js variable I want to be concatenated too within a jQuery selector. However it is not working. No errors are popping up either. What is wrong? How do I correctly concatenate a variable to some text in a jQuery selector.

```
<div id="part2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$('#button').click(function () 
{
var text = $('#text').val();    
var number = 2;
$.post('ajaxskeleton.php', {
red: text       
}, 
    function(){
    $('#part' + number).html(text);
    }); 
});


</script>
```

Comment: You should create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @ason328, do you know about the `console.log()`. With its help, by placing it in interesting lines, you can see what is going on in your code step by step

Comment: No, I was unaware of it. I'll look into that now.

Comment: @valentinas jsfiddle isn't great for testing AJAX code

Comment: can you post the whole code? it doesn't work without the #text and #button divs right now - also your div id needs to start as part, not part2

Comment: @Alnitak it _is_ great for testing AJAX code. They have an acho api for XML, JSON, HTML, etc.. Here's the documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: @valentinas what I meant is that it's not good for testing calls to your _own_ AJAX calls, unless you can override the cross origin policies.

Comment: @Alnitak there is no need to do your own AJAX calls - api is there to simulate them. You can specify what output you want to get and that way skip the back-end altogether.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with syntax of

```
$('#part' + number).html(text);
```

jQuery accepts a String (*usually a CSS Selector*) or a [DOM Node](http://javascript.info/tutorial/dom-nodes) as parameter to create a [jQuery Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445180/what-is-a-jquery-object).

In your case you should pass a String to `$()` that is

```
$(<a string>)
```

Make sure you have access to the variables `number` and `text`.

To test do:

```
function(){
    alert(number + ":" + text);//or use console.log(number + ":" + text)
    $('#part' + number).html(text);
});
```

If you see you dont have access, pass them as parameters to the function, you have to include the uual parameters for $.get and pass the custom parameters after them.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the clear explanation. My var number was called undefined, which I quickly fixed.

Comment: Gald that its fixed. But now Im confused, How did you fix it? :)

Comment: Noob error. I was calling the var number outside the click event.

Answer (score 4):

Your concatenation syntax is correct.

Most likely the callback function isn't even being called.  You can test that by putting an `alert()`, `console.log()` or `debugger` line in that function.

If it isn't being called, most likely there's an AJAX error.  Look at chaining a `.fail()` handler after `$.post()` to find out what the error is, e.g.:

```
$.post('ajaxskeleton.php', {
    red: text       
}, function(){
    $('#part' + number).html(text);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: what is the scope inside the $.get call back? will the variables number and text be accessible there?

Comment: @sabithpocker  if your above code is complete, then `number` and `text` will be accessible because they're part of the _lexical scope_.  The "gotcha" variable in callbacks is `this`, but you're not using that.