# How to convert variable value into jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

For some reason I need to convert jquery variable value into object.

```
$("input[type=text]").on("keyup", function () {
    var target = this.id; //outputs 'subject'
    //how to convert here?
    var targetItem = $("#subject");//originally like this.
    //I tried something like below
    //var targetItem = $("#+target+");
    alert(targetItem);
});
```

All I'm trying to do is , changing the word in this: `$("#subject")` with
whatever value of variable 'target'.

Comment: var targetItem = $("#"+target);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134605/concatenate-in-jquery-selector/12134652#12134652

Comment: just one doubt. Why do you need this code? because object which you will get is same one you get by simply using `this`

Comment: if `this` refers to the `node` you can just do `$(this)`

Comment: Provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue because your posted code doesn't make sense or maybe your example sample isn't relevant to your use case issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply like

```
var target = this.id;
var targetItem = $("#"+target);
```

Comment: But because IDs must be unique on document context, it doesn't make sense

Comment: @soosmca  No need id value ,You can use this directly **$(this)**

Comment: @Balachandran - I am just notices what mistake the OP had done

Comment: That is good but i gave suggestion  you can wrap *this* with $ directly

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` -

```
var targetItem = $(this); // Will always hold the current element object
```

And for the code you are using it should be -

```
var targetItem = $("#" + target);
```

`target` is a variable. `"#+target+"` will be treated as `#+target+` not `#subject` (in your case)

Comment: You can also please correct the way he is trying to concatenate `string`s

Comment: @sabithpocker :) Thanks.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you for doing my part :P

Comment: @sabithpocker You Are Welcome. ;)