# Create an associative array in jquery from hidden hashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hash

I am trying to create an associative array from hidden hashes. The jquery below calls to the specific hashes, but I would like to create this dynamically with one code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tokens").tokenInput([
         {id: 1, name: "Darren Criss"},
         {id: 2, name: "Ann Arbor T-shirt Company"},
         {id: 3, name: "StarKid Product Store"},
     ]);
 });
```

I tried to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var variable = $("input[type='hidden'][class='stores']").val();
      $("#tokens").tokenInput(variable);
 });
```

but it doesnt work.

here are the hashes

```
  <input id="1" class="stores" type="hidden" value="Darren Criss" taxonomies_count="9"  
 name="1" disabled="disabled"></input>

 <input id="2" class="stores" type="hidden" value="Ann Arbor T-shirt Company" 
 taxonomies_count="46" name="2" disabled="disabled"></input>

 <input id="3" class="stores" type="hidden" value="StarKid Productions Store" 
 taxonomies_count="22" name="3" disabled="disabled"></input>
```

Comment: What's typed into that text input? At the very least, you'll need to `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your question. Can you be more specific with your question and suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you gave as the source are not hashes but HTML input tags. If you want to extract values from them, you can use [jquery's `attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$(function(){
  var tokens = $('.stores').map(function(index, el) {
     var element = $(el)
     return {
       id: element.attr('id'),
       name: element.attr('value')
     }
  })
  $("#tokens").tokenInput(tokens);
});
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the hashes once you have them, but that should get you started.

Comment: your code is great too! it work perfectly. I actually like this one better because I can understand it more.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code calls `tokenInput`, but only passes it a single string (the value of the first `input` element encountered in the DOM. Assuming that these hashes are present in the DOM when the `document` loads,

```
  var val = $("input[type='hidden'][class='stores']").val();
  $("#tokens").tokenInput(val);
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
$("#tokens").tokenInput("Darren Criss");
```

which does not match the kind of argument expected by `tokenInput` (see http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/#installation--setup) (You seem to have the right idea in your first code example). Why not iterate over a jQuery `input` selection, pushing new hash objects into a list, and, finally, call tokenInput, passing it the complete list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hashes = [];
    $('input.stores').each(function(i, elem) {
        hashes.push({
            'id': $(elem).attr('id'),
            'name': $(elem).val(),
        });
    });
    console.log(hashes);
    //$('#tokens').tokenInput(hashes);
});
```

**EDIT:**

> what is the i and the elem?

My approach is using jQuery's built-in iterator function `each` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). This utility function allows programmers to easily iterate over existing collections, including objects, arrays, and jQuery selections. Here is the function's signature (for lack of a better term) as seen in jQuery's documentation:

*jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )*

You can call `each` on any iterable JavaScript object (e.g. - `foo.each(...);`), although it is more common to see a jQuery selection preceeding the call. `each` expects you to pass it a callback function that accepts two arguments: an index/key argument, and a value/item argument (as a side note, you also have access to `this`, an implicit argument referencing the value/item) inside of the body of the callback.

`each` will call this function once for each item in the collection, automatically passing it the appropriate index/key and value arguments for you, based on the current item in the iteration. jQuery selections are iterable *array-like* objects: they *behave* like JavaScript arrays, and their 'items' can be referenced using numerical indexes (e.g. — Calling `$('div')[0]` or `$('div').get(0)` will return a reference to first DOM element matching the `div` selector, if a div is present on the page).

When we iterate over a jQuery selection, the 'items' that we are iterating over are references to DOM elements. In my example, when I call `each` on a jQuery selection and provide it with a callback function, `i` is given the value of the current DOM element's index within the selection, while `elem` references the actual element. Oftentimes we want to call jQuery methods on these elements inside of the callback function. This requires us to *wrap* the element as a jQuery object (`$(elem)`), allowing us to manipulate the element using all of jQuery's functionality.

Conventionally, calling `each` on a jQuery selection follows this form:

```
$('your selector here').each(function(i,elem) {
    var foo = $(elem); //Allows us to treat the DOM element as a jQuery object
    //Do stuff ... foo.val().attr().css().toggle();
});
```

Further reading on jQuery objects:

- http://www.elijahmanor.com/2013/02/jquery-object-quacks-like-array-duck.html
- [What is a jQuery Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445180/what-is-a-jquery-object#answer-6445357)

> and what does console.log(hashes);

I've simply included a `console.log()` to let you explore the hash list that is generated. It is not necessary for calling `tokenInput`.

Comment: what is the i and the elem? and what does console.log(hashes); mean? noob over here sorry