# Why add [0] when declaring a variable for canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

In this code :

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Why do we have to add `[0]` to identify the canvas? It's a bit confusing for me, because `[n]` is usually added when there are multiple elements with the same name and we need to address a particular one. But an id can only refer to one unique element.

Comment: jQuery selectors can return multiple objects, so they always return something that looks like an array.  IMHO, better just to use `canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')`

Comment: ... or `document.querySelector("#myCanvas")` if you need more complex selectors.

Comment: because to use javascript methods like getContext() you need to return the actual dom element and not the jQuery array. For example, doing $("body").innerHTML will give you undefined but $("body")[0].innerHTML will return the contents of body.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is used to retrieve the underlying canvas DOMElement from the jQuery object so that the `getContext()` method (which the jQuery object does not have) can be used.

```
$('#myCanvas')                      // = canvas DOMElement wrapped in a jQuery object
$('#myCanvas')[0]                   // = canvas DOMElement
document.getElementById('myCanvas') // = canvas DOMElement
```

See also:

[What is a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445180/what-is-a-jquery-object)

[canvas API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery *always* returns an array-like object, even if you use a (unique) id as the selector.

In your case the `[0]` is to return the first (and only) actual element.

Comment: @Oriol - yes, I knew that. It was a case of typing too quickly before brain was engaged. Thanks for pointing out my mistake