# Hook jQuery methods on JavaScript selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Easier to explain with simple code:

`$("#element").fadeOut(); // jQuery; works as expected`

I want to use `.fadeOut()` and select element with JS like this:

`document.getElementById("element").fadeOut(); // Does not work`

How do I make this work and is there any point of doing this (performance wise)?

Any thought is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: jQuery methods expect a jQuery Object in order to work. E.g. `$()`  See more info about them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445180/what-is-a-jquery-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `fadeOut` property name to `HTMLElement.prototype`, and call jQuery's `fadeOut` from inside it:

```js
// $("#element").fadeOut(); // jQuery; works as expected

HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOut = function(...args) {
  $(this).fadeOut(...args);
}

document.getElementById('element').fadeOut();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element">text</div>
```

That said, overwriting built-in objects like `HTMLElement` is pretty bad practice and can cause problems - it would be better to just do what you were doing originally, and call `.fadeOut` on a jQuery object containing the desired element(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the element in `$()`:

```
$(document.getElementById("element")).fadeOut();
```

However, you may find it's easier just to use the jQuery ID selector `#`:

```
$('#element').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery features, you need to use `$()` to call the method i.e. `fadeout()`. See [JQuery Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

Now that if you want to do it in vanilla JavaScript then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017379/how-to-make-fadeout-effect-with-pure-javascript) out.