# Are arrays stored contiguously in all languages?

Tags: arrays, programming-languages

I was reading a blog recently that made a big deal about array data being stored contiguously (specifically in Go), but it was my understanding that by definition, array data is stored contiguously. At least this is what all my algorithms and data structures study has led me to believe.

So my question is, is array data stored contiguously in all programming languages? And, specifically I want to talk about primitives like integers (or in the case of Java where I can have an array of Objects, are the references to the objects stored contiguously in memory? I know that the objects themselves can be anywhere).

Comment: for java there is already an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224888/java-are-1-d-arrays-always-contiguous-in-memory

Comment: For Java there's no rule that array elements be stored contiguously or in any particular order, so long as the specified behaviors occur.  The C languages generally require contiguous order for single-dimension arrays so that pointer semantics are assured.  Likely there are several languages which use an "ArrayList" type mechanism for arrays, and arrays may be constructed from multiple non-contiguous blocks.

Comment: Many language specifications consider this to be implementation detail (what is memory?) and don't guarantee it, but it's usually the case in actual implementations.

Comment: It's not true in the language I'm going to invent next year. Just to spite you.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you define as an "array" on a language, although the traditional meaning of an array has to do with contiguous element placing.

For instance, in `JavaScript`, arrays are in fact hash tables, which means that data are not stored in contiguously but are hashed based on its indexing keys (using a hash function) to store the values in different addresses (questioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445010/what-is-a-javascript-array)), and this is only an example (in fact, I think that in dynamic languages it is a common phenomenon to have arrays as hash tables).

I suppose that this one answers your question with a *no*.

Answer (score 0):

usually this is below language abstraction level so there is no explicit requirement about that. but any real-life implementation probably does that (with rounding to word size) because of performance. it refers to virtual memory of course, because kernel can provide non-contiguous space that the program itself sees as contiguous